# Start a workflow on page activation without activating the page in CQ5

Tags: adobe, aem

I would need to call a workflow whenever a content author clicks activate on a page. The workflow would then send a notification to the administrator, who then proceeds to activate the page.

Let me explain this with some more detail. There are 2 parts to this

i) Whenever a content author is done modifying a page, he would then proceed to click "**Activate Page**" from either the sidekick or from page properties on the siteadmin. By doing so, he is not activating the page straight away but calling a workflow.

ii) The workflow will send out a notification to the admin, who then decides to activate the page. This bit is fairly ordinary, so no issues here.

All of this is an effort to make sure that there is nothing published/activated unless it has been reviewed by an admin.

I tried setting up a ReplicationEvent listener that would call a workflow. What happens is that the page is already activated *before* the workflow is called; the occurrence of a *ReplicationEvent* is only after said Replication Event (i.e Activate) occurs (Obviously!).

As stated, I need to make sure that the page isn't actually activated when the user clicks activate; which means I need to modify what the activate button does exactly.

I have tried looking up online, but found nothing, which leads me to believe that most of CQ5's siteadmin code is hidden from us and cannot be modified (and with good reason).

So is there anything else that anyone can think of which may help me to achieve my requirement? Or should I give this up as a lost cause?

Thanks in advance and apologies for the long post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could put the authors in a user group that does not have replication permissions. When an author tries to activate a page without the permissions, it automatically starts the `request for activation` workflow. I think the default config has one step for content approval and a separate step for activation. Both steps are mapped to the administrator user group. The workflows are at `http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/workflow/content/console.html` and you can double click on a model to edit it.

Comment: has this worked for you? because when i try logging in as author and activate any page, it denies the action, but there is no workflow triggered.

I haven't found any information about this in their official documentation [link] (http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/security.html) on this topic either.

Comment: Which version of cq are you using? From the [docs](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/wcm/page_publish.html) it looks like in 5.6+ the workflow will automatically start when a user fails to activate. You can also set the workflow off manually through the workflow tab in the sidekick.

Comment: i did see that in the docs for ReplicatePageProcess. im using 5.6.

my requirements need me to trigger the workflow on clicking activate, though, as stated above, so I guess setting the workflow manually is out

Comment: My 5.6 works fine. I started a new instance, created a user without replication permissions, and tried to activate a geometrixx page. It spits out `Warn: No rights to replicate. Request for de/activation got issued for /content/dam/geometrixx/packshots/pack_square.jpg` and starts a workflow. You should be able to see the message in the admin's inbox (`http://localhost:4502/notifications.html`)

Comment: Strangely; the workflow gets called when I create a new user from scratch; and not when I change the rights of any preexisting user.

Thanks a lot btw :D

Answer (score 4):

You can use [replication preprocessor](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/replication/Preprocessor.html) ([example](https://gist.github.com/cqtips/5075871)) which is something like replication event listener but is invoked *before* the activation is done. Throwing exception in the `preprocess()` method will stop activation process and display exception message.

However, more elegant option is to use ACL to forbid an user to activate the page. After that, clicking **Activate** button won't publish the page but will rather invoke **Request for Activation** workflow.

Comment: just wondering if a replication preprocessor is the best way to go about it. Wouldn't invoking a **request for activation** workflow in this way set up a never ending loop of sorts when the administrator tries to activate the page?

Comment: The replication preprocessor should disable activation only for selected user/group (not for admin). But I agree that the second way (using ACL rather than preprocessor) is a better option.

Comment: hmm.. is there a way to attach a workflow through ACL on activate? or does it do that automatically?

i tried logging in as "author", and activating the page; while it does deny the activation, it does not initiate a **Request for activation** workflow. Doesn't really say anything about workflows here either :- [link](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/security.html)