# Start a workflow on page activation without activating the page in AEM 6.2

Tags: workflow, aem

I need a setup where users can update a page and then submit it for approval/activation in AEM 6.2. The page would be submitted to workflow where a content approver/administrator would review and publish the page. This seems like a common setup for content managment, but I can't figure out how to do it in AEM.

I have done the following:

- setup a user that has permission to update but does NOT have
  replicate permission on folderX.
- setup users with update and replicate permissions on folderX and added them to a group "content-authors-approvers"
- created a workflow where the first step of the workflow is the page will be submitted for approval and publication to member of "content-authors-approvers" group
- assigned this workflow to folderX

However, when a user does NOT have replicate permission, the "publish" option does not show up at all.  This makes sense, really....but then, how does one go about setting up a workflow like this?

From what I've read about this in earlier versions of AEM/CQ5, the replicate/publish option was still available to all users, but it would automatically kick off workflow if the user did not have replicate permissions.  (see [Start a workflow on page activation without activating the page in CQ5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864317/start-a-workflow-on-page-activation-without-activating-the-page-in-cq5) )

this seems to have changed in 6.2.  can anyone help?

I have tried looking up online, but found nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a native workflow to handle that. It's named `Publish Example`. see it here: http://localhost:4502/etc/workflow/models/publish_example.html . I believe that it's better then the automatic triggering cause the author actually knows he triggers a workflow (whilst when it happened automatically there was no info about that). To explicitly call it you have to either from `/siteadmin` select a page and click workflow on it, or do it from sidekick or in touch.

sidekick:

[image]

touch - editpage:

[image]

Comment: thank you.  I found that workflow.  I'm researching how to give my users access to a workflow  https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/administer/operations/workflows/managing.html